# Amazon DynamoDB GSI

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code which I am trying to run on local dynamodb. This is to create a table and a global secondary index along with it.

```
 var params = {
        TableName: 'dev_GeoActivity',
        KeySchema: [ // The type of of schema.  Must start with a HASH type, with an optional second RANGE.
            { // Required HASH type attribute
                AttributeName: 'primaryKey',
                KeyType: 'HASH',
            }

        ],
        AttributeDefinitions: [ // The names and types of all primary and index key attributes only
            {
                AttributeName: 'primaryKey',
                AttributeType: 'S', // (S | N | B) for string, number, binary
            },
            {
                AttributeName: 'customerID',
                AttributeType: 'S', // (S | N | B) for string, number, binary
            },
            {
                AttributeName: 'time',
                AttributeType: 'S', // (S | N | B) for string, number, binary
            },

        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput: { // required provisioned throughput for the table
            ReadCapacityUnits: 400, 
            WriteCapacityUnits: 400, 
        },
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [ // optional (list of GlobalSecondaryIndex)
            { 
                IndexName: 'highestYTD', 
                KeySchema: [
                    { // Required HASH type attribute
                        AttributeName: 'customerID',
                        KeyType: 'HASH',
                    },
                    { // Optional RANGE key type for HASH + RANGE secondary indexes
                        AttributeName: 'time', 
                        KeyType: 'RANGE', 
                    }
                ],
                Projection: { // attributes to project into the index
                    ProjectionType: 'INCLUDE', // (ALL | KEYS_ONLY | INCLUDE)
                    NonKeyAttributes: [ // required / allowed only for INCLUDE
                        'location',
                        'adId'
                        // ... more attribute names ...
                    ],
                },
                ProvisionedThroughput: { // throughput to provision to the index
                    ReadCapacityUnits: 400,
                    WriteCapacityUnits: 400,
                },
            },
            // ... more global secondary indexes ...
        ],

    };
    dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){ ppJson(err); console.log(this.httpResponse.body.toString());} // an error occurred
        else ppJson(data); // successful response

    });
```

It gives me the following error:

```
The request processing has failed because of an error, exception or failure.
statusCode:500
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The create script seems to be working fine. Could you please print the  "err" object in console and update the question rather than the HTTP error message?

Comment: `statusCode:500` means internal error. so your request seems to be fine, but something's going wrong with the DDB local's daemon